# How to run tensorflow retrain.py from other script?

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

I am writing a script to automate a training using the main() function in the [tensorflow retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py). This script is normally called from the shell with parsed arguments. In retrain.py:

```
if __name__ == __main__:
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument(
      '--image_dir',
      type=str,
      default='',
      help='Path to folders of labeled images.'
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      '--output_graph',
      type=str,
      default='/tmp/output_graph.pb',
      help='Where to save the trained graph.'
  )

  ...

  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

I understand that tensorflow usually handles the `FLAGS` argument as global variable, but I don't understand how this variable is set as global, since in the code snippet, `FLAGS` should be an `argparse.Namespace` object.

However, I've  tried to define the `FLAGS` variable manually in my own script:

```
from scripts.retrain import main

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('summaries_dir', summaries_dir, 'Help summaries_dir.')
  tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', image_dir, 'Help image_dir.')

  ...

  FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + ['python -m scripts.retrain.py'])
```

And always get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'summaries_dir'`. How should I run the retrain.py from my script?